# Was this answer for posting using HttpURLConnection in Java/Android plagiarised?

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I found a particular user who's been plagiarising a lot of answers. Most of the cases of plagiarism have been easy to verify using Google. However, I'm currently having trouble determining whether or not the following answer has also been plagiarised (dated 2015-04-10):

> Since the NameValuePair is deprecated. Thought of sharing my code
>
> ```java
> public String  performPostCall(String requestURL,
>           HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {
>
>       URL url;
>       String response = "";
>       try {
>           url = new URL(requestURL);
>
>           HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
>           conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
>           conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
>           conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
>           conn.setDoInput(true);
>           conn.setDoOutput(true);
>
>
>           OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
>           BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
>                   new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
>           writer.write(getPostData(postDataParams));
>
>           writer.flush();
>           writer.close();
>           os.close();
>           int responseCode=conn.getResponseCode();
>
>           if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
>               String line;
>               BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
>               while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {
>                   response+=line;
>               }
>           }
>           else {
>               response="";
>
>               throw new HttpException(responseCode+"");
>           }
>       } catch (Exception e) {
>           e.printStackTrace();
>       }
>
>       return response;
>   }
> ```
>
> ....
>
> ```java
>   private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
>       StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
>       boolean first = true;
>       for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()){
>           if (first)
>               first = false;
>           else
>               result.append("&");
>
>           result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
>           result.append("=");
>           result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
>       }
>
>       return result.toString();
>     }
> ```

I've been searching for things like the function names and some code snippets in Google. I haven't found anything that looks like it's definitely an original source. In fact, I found many hits that all share a similar pattern:

1. [can use httpClient in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31653061/456814)
2. [Https post request, from html to java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31083793/456814)
3. [WebCams - PerformPostCall.java](https://github.com/TomasValenta/WebCams/blob/master/app/src/main/java/cz/yetanotherview/webcamviewer/app/helper/PerformPostCall.java)

I'm not an Android/Java expert. Is this a common pattern to use when making HTTP requests in Android/Java? Including the `private` helper method? Is this based off a code sample from documentation or something? Because if any of that is true, then this is probably not a true case of plagiarism.

Comment: Earliest (non-deleted) I could find: [21 Nov 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13486223/5240004) Seems like some of those questions are duplicates... seeing as the _exact_ same answer is valid. Also, the one where this same routine was translated to VB 6 is my personal favorite [3 Apr 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15788668/5240004) That all said this does look an awful lot like boilerplate.

Comment: Well, if that's the code you have to write to do a simple connection request I have no wonder that people just copy & paste the code of someone else instead of rewriting it from scratch...

Comment: It looks pretty common to me, and in my experience, a lot of code that involves http requests and/or reading streams (ie `OutputStream` and `BufferedReader`, etc) looks a lot like this. It's all a pretty basic (and annoyingly long) way to handle making a request. But I would not be surprised if it were copy-pasted, maybe with minor modifications.